# Iterating through an array of mongo documents and getting the count for a nested array property?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an array of hotels with a shape like so:

```
[
  {
      "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
      "Reviews" : [ 
          {
              "Ratings" : {
                  "Service" : 4.0,
                  "Cleanliness" : "4",
                  "Overall" : 4.0,
                  "Value" : 4.0,
                  "Sleep Quality" : "4",
                  "Rooms" : "4",
                  "Location" : "5"
              },
              "AuthorLocation" : "...",
              "Title" : "...",
              "Author" : "...",
              "ReviewID" : "...",
              "Content" : "...",
              "Date" : ISODate("...")
          }, 
          {
              "Ratings" : {
                  "Cleanliness" : "5",
                  "Overall" : 5.0,
                  "Value" : 4.0,
                  "Service" : 5.0,
                  "Rooms" : "5"
              },
              "AuthorLocation" : "...",
              "Title" : "...",
              "Author" : "...",
              "ReviewID" : "...",
              "Content" : "...",
              "Date" : ISODate("...")
          }
      ],
      "HotelInfo" : {
          "Name" : "Hilton Garden Inn Baltimore White Marsh",
          "HotelURL" : "...",
          "Price" : "...",
          "Address" : "...",
          "HotelID" : "...",
          "ImgURL" : "..."
      }
  },
  ... // More hotel entries
]
```

What I am basically trying to do is go through each one of these hotel documents in the array and get a list of objects with the hotel name and how many 5 star `"Overall"` ratings it has.

Desired output:

```
{ _id: "Hiltop Inn", numberOfFiveStarReviews: 3 },
{ _id: "Hot Hotel", numberOfFiveStarReviews: 2 },
{ _id: "Cool Hotel", numberOfFiveStarReviews: 6 }
```

etc

I've been stuck on this awhile and have tried various things with `filter` or other aggregation stuff, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Here's what I have so far:

```
db.reviews.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$Reviews" },
  { $unwind: "$Reviews.Ratings" },
  { 
      $group : { 
          _id: "$HotelInfo.Name", 
          countOfFiveStarRatings: {  
              // NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE
          } 
      } 
  }
])
```

Not sure if there's a better approach to go about it, but this is what I've been playing with for awhile. I'm a bit new to MongoDB, so any help would definitely be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: 1) Your desired output doesn't match with your sample document. 2) How the 5 star rating will be counted?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Sorry for not explaining well, the desired output was basically just an example, and my actual data set has more hotels (this only has 1, the `Hilton Garden Inn Baltimore White Marsh`.) To get the 5 star rating count, it is basically just getting the count of `"Overall"` properties in the reviews where the value is `5`. In just the data I show above, there are 2 reviews for the hotel, and one gave an overall of 4 and one gave an overall of 5. So in this instance, the desired output would be `{ _id: "Hilton Garden Inn Baltimore White Mars", numberOfFiveStarReviews: 1 }`

Comment: But there are more hotel entries in the top level array in my actual data, I basically just have one hotel entry shown in the example above

Comment: Was able to solve it, thanks for taking the time @AnthonyWinzlet. I'll try to do a better job of posting my questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this after learning that I could keep doing `project` and using the past results until I end up with what I want.

Solution:

```
db.reviews.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$Reviews" },
    { $unwind: "$Reviews.Ratings" },
    {
        $group : {
            _id: "$HotelInfo.Name",
            reviews: {
                $push: "$Reviews.Ratings.Overall"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            fiveStarReviews: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$reviews",
                    as: "rev",
                    cond: {
                        $eq: ["$$rev", 5]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            name: "$_id",
            countOfFiveStarReviews: {
                $size: "$fiveStarReviews"
            }
        }
    }
])
```